# Two-way binding in Swift Combine

Tags: swift, two-way-binding, combine

I have a progress bar and a text field, both are updated depending on each other's input:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var progressBarValue: Double {
        didSet {
            textFieldValue = String(progressBarValue)
        }
    }
    @Published var textFieldValue: String {
        didSet {
            progressBarValue = Double(progressBarValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Since updating one updates the other, I end up having an infinite recursion in my code.

Is there a way to workaround this with Combine or plain swift code?

Comment: Apple (in their combine/swiftui talks & docs) always stresses out the benefits of a _single source of truth_. In your case that would be a **single** `value` that both controls observe and update (via Bindings), without ever interacting with each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, here is a minimal example of a slider and a textfield that both control (and be controlled by) a value via two-way bindings:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var progress: Double = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", value: self.$model.progress, formatter: NumberFormatter())
            Slider(value: self.$model.progress, in: 0...100)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(ViewModel())
    }
}
```

Note that I also had to inject a `ViewModel` instance to my environment on AppDelegate in order for this to work (both on preview & actual app)

Comment: That's a very elegant way to solve it, thank you so much!

Comment: @JAHelia Think of it this way: instead of setting each control's value, I will just set _a_ value and let them update when that changes... No calls from one to another in order to sync up...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe additional checks to avoid loops will work?

```swift
@Published var progressBarValue: Double {
    didSet {
        let newText = String(progressBarValue)

        if newText != textFieldValue {
            textFieldValue = newText
        }
    }
}
@Published var textFieldValue: String {
    didSet {
        if let newProgress = Double(textFieldValue),
            abs(newProgress - progressBarValue) > Double.ulpOfOne {
            progressBarValue = newProgress
        }
    }
}
```